# how do i make java code that reads a word and tells me if is starts with the letter a or not? i am lost

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IfAndString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Word:"); 
        String line = input.next();

        char a = line.charAt(2);
        char b = line.charAt(2);

        if (a < b)
            System.out.printf("%s starts with 'a'.",a);
        else if (a > b)
            System.out.printf("\n%s does not start with 'a'.",b);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should describe what exactly is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Won't `a` and `b` both be the same char? In any case, `java.lang.String` has had `startsWith(String prefix)` since version 1.0

Comment: Input value: mineral
 ""mineral" does not start with 'a'."
This is what the program is suppose to do... i know my code is wrong but don't know how to fix it ...

Comment: If you care about what the String *starts* with, why are you taking the third character (index of 2) of the String? Regardless, as a and b are the same, a is neither less than nor greater than b; nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Anwser to your question in the headline. Simply use the Method boolean startsWith(String string) method from the String class, e.g. like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IfAndString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Word:"); 
        String line = input.next();

       if (line.startsWith("a")){
           System.out.printf("%s starts with 'a'.",a);
       } else{
           System.out.printf("\n%s does not start with 'a'.",b);
       }
    }
}
```

When you want to compare chars do something like this:

```
"abc".charAt(0) == 'a'; // String implement CharSequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startsWith()` method

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Word:"); 
    String line = input.next();

    if (line.startsWith("a"))
    {
        System.out.println(line + ": starts with a");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("does not start with a");
    }
}
```

Also if you wanted to check for an `a` even if they entered an uppercase `A` you could change your line variable to lower case in the if check to account for both lowercase and uppercase `a`.

Example:

```
if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("a"))
```